# Tiny Eyes Addon problem

Tags: lighting, reflection

I faced a problem that for some reason when I use Tiny Eyes addon pupils always reflect the light in a strange way - they are just yellow. I tried different things but couldn'find anything on youtube neither. And all tutorials show perfectly reflected eyes and mine are just like this. Does anyone know what the problem might be. Attched the file just in case
https://workupload.com/file/Rj2eXtVTBw4
[image]

Answer (score 2):

What you see in the eyes is the skin of the face. When you hide the pupils you can see that the eye sockets are not open, so you have skin inside the eye. The pupils are basically a hole in the eye (not a black surface), or in this model more formed like a tunnel. So inside the hole of the pupil there is skin.

[image: eye sockets]

Comment: Oh, so if I make holes inside eyes then the reflection should be fine, right?

Comment: @AnastasiaAmirova In the eye sockets, not the eyes ;) But yes, that should work.

Comment: Yeah, it worked! Thank you a lot!! You literally my life saver! I've been searching for answer for a while!

Comment: @AnastasiaAmirova It's a bit sad that although I "saved your life" you do not bother to appreciate this by accepting the answer. Please read: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers)